# return multiple audio files to stream in single request

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

I am currently building an Alexa app and have it pretty much ready. I am just having a small issues when it comes to trying to stream multiple audio files in one request.

Right now, every time the user makes a request the app return a single audio file inside the `res.directives` array. When this audio file has almost finished streaming, and my app gets the `AudioPlayer.PlaybackNearlyFinished` request, I send the next audio file to stream in the same way. Is it possible I can just send all the audio files with the first request, so the device does not have to keep fetching the next audio file?

`res.directives` is an array, so I presume this is possible, but I cannot find documentation to show how.

Comment: hey Tuqire Hussain, I'm trying to do what you mentioned with AudioPlayer.PlaybackNearlyFinished, but I can't even seem to get that to work. My PlaybackNearlyFinished gets called. I respond with the next file, but it never gets played. Here's my second call. this.response.audioPlayerPlay('ENQUEUE', 'https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/some_file.mp3', 'newToken', 'prevToken', 0);

Comment: Hi @Khon apologies for late reply.

I am returning json from my endpoint. Are you using some sort of SDK?

Comment: my full response object

```"response": {
    "directives": [
      {
        "type": "AudioPlayer.Play",
        "playBehavior": "REPLACE_ALL",
        "audioItem": {
          "stream": {
            "url": "https://cdn.audiourl.com",
            "offsetInMilliseconds": 0,
            "token": "1234"
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "shouldEndSession": true
  }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI asked this question on Amazon DEveloper forum, and got a reply: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/112506/can-directives-object-take-an-array-of-audio-files.html